# Need help regarding programming challenges solving algorithms

Tags: algorithm

I want to improve my programming skills, when I participate in some programming competition I feel that every challenge is so tough that i can not solve it,I have good knowledge of coding but I fell to decide the algorithm needed to solve particular problem for that can anyone tell me which books to read

Comment: This question is mostly opinion based. StackOverflow stands for specific situations.

Comment: Its all perception . You just need learn on experience so it will last long , as you say "every challenge is so tough that i can not solve " , this may hold good for first time when you see so kind of problem , so first you may fail and learn , but next time you had an experience of it once , it this is how it worked for me , and yes books are quick source , but try to get own experience also it matter a lot  .. And this is off the topic anyhow welcome to stackoverflow ..!! ;)

Comment: Practice solving simple programming questions on TopCoder, HackerRank, HackerEarth, CodeChef, SPOJ and many other sites. Practice makes a man perfect!

Comment: MissingNumber & vishram0709 i tried solving problems from the suggested site i done pretty good coding stuff on that site but while participating in any hackenthon i fell to solve all challenges just lack of knowledge about the mathematical formulas and algorithms .. but still i will try to imporvise .. Thanks Man for you suggesions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest first to get comfortable with programming language of your choice. Once you have confidence on your language and Data structure, you can proceed confidently for any programming challenges. Make a habit of writing complete code with all edge cases handled on a sheet of paper rather than simple pseudo code for your practice session.

Now to solve algorithmic problem first to grasp elementary algo functioning via book or online resources. If you are using coreman (good book for algo) then you might want to understand basic concepts of different sorting techniques, heap, queue, hashing, greedy and dynamic algorithm. For some topic i would recommend to research online as well - like dynamic programming and hashing. Almost 70-80% interview questions are either hashing or DP based. Then look for major examples and their solution for these algorithm. Once your mind will set up you would be able to think quickly for any algorithmic problem.

Comment: Thanks man .. i will do the needed

Answer (score 0):

`Introduction to Algorithms` by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest , Clifford Stein is a good one to start with.
Covers almost everything, from graph theory to geometric algorithms and all related data structures, furthermore they use the commonly used "Big O" notation to indicate the efficiency of the algorithms explained. Most of the time multiple algorithms are presented for the same problem, together with their advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks man .. can u suggest any book which covers mathmatical formulas and tricks to solve the given problem in quick way ??

Comment: The book I suggested most of the time uses mathematics to explain the problem and to prove the pseudo code. They take a problem, make it more abstract using math and solve it using pseudo code.
For pure mathematical algorithms that can solve almost every problem see the Linear Programming and Graph theory chapters. With these two you entered a whole new world of problem solving :) However, you might want to start simple by looking into (efficient) sorting and searching of arrays to get familiar with algorithms in general and notation.

Comment: Thanks Man .. I looking forward to it .. :)